# splash screen and one time intro in flutter

Tags: dart, flutter, splash-screen

I want my splash screen to always appear in my application and it does which is great, but I have a walk through after the splash screen and I want it to be a one time walk through, So i want to add an integer to the shared preferences with a value of 0 and everytime I open the splash screen the value is incremented by one, so when "number" equals 1 or greater at the second run the splash screen skips the walkthrough and goes to home , here is the code that I want to edit now :

```
void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    Timer(Duration(seconds: 5), () => MyNavigator.goToIntro(context));
}
```

And I want it to be like :

```
void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();int number=0;//this is in the shared prefs
    Timer(Duration(seconds: 5), () => if(number==0){MyNavigator.goToIntro(context));
    }else{MyNavigator.goToHome(context));
    number++;}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The below code prints perfectly as we expect(during first launch only, "First launch"). You can use your navigation logic instead of print.

```
@override
void initState() {
    super.initState();
    setValue();
}

void setValue() async {
    final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    int launchCount = prefs.getInt('counter') ?? 0;
    prefs.setInt('counter', launchCount + 1);
    if (launchCount == 0) {
        print("first launch"); //setState to refresh or move to some other page
    } else {
        print("Not first launch");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

We need to have the `number` value to be saved across multiple app launches. We can use [shared_preference](https://flutter.io/cookbook/persistence/key-value/) plugin to achieve this.

Comment: i know we can achieve this but I tried and couldnt do so can you show me how @Dinesh Balasubramanian

Answer (score 0):

at first, let's save the data as boolean

```
Future<void> saveData() async {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    bool isIntroScreenOpened = true;
    sharedPreferences.setBool("isIntroScreenOpened", isIntroScreenOpened); // saved data to your device.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

secondly, `getData` that saved in our device.

```
Future<bool> getSaveData() async {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    bool isIntroScreenOpenedBefore =
        sharedPreferences.getBool("isIntroScreenOpened") ?? false;
    print(sharedPreferences.containsKey("isIntroScreenOpened")); // check your key either it is save or not? 

    if (isIntroScreenOpenedBefore == true) {
      Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) {
        return LoginBoard();
      }));
    } else {
      Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) {
        return WalKThroughScreen();
      }));
    }
    return isIntroScreenOpenedBefore;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

## **Answer by @Dinesh Balasubramanian is works really fine.**

But I have 4 initial screen that need to show once. I have done that using same logic in each screen. and then my app was showing 5th screen second time like fast forwarding all the previous screen and stopping on 5th screen.

To resolve this I am getting all the set Preferences at main.dart to open directly 5th screen. but when I do that I am having this problem,

> "E/flutter (32606): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(186)]
> Unhandled Exception: Navigator operation requested with a context that
> does not include a Navigator.
>
> E/flutter (32606): The context used to
> push or pop routes from the Navigator must be that of a widget that is
> a descendant of a Navigator widget."

Here is code to switch from main.dart:

```
int firstLogin, firstMobile, firstOtp, firstInfo;
  void setValue() async {
    final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    firstLogin = prefs.getInt('counterLogin') ?? 0;
    firstMobile = prefs.getInt('counterMobile') ?? 0;
    firstOtp = prefs.getInt('counterOtp') ?? 0;
    firstInfo = prefs.getInt('counterInfo') ?? 0;

    prefs.setInt('counterLogin', firstLogin + 1);
    prefs.setInt('counterMobile', firstMobile + 1);
    prefs.setInt('counterOtp', firstOtp + 1);
    prefs.setInt('counterInfo', firstInfo + 1);

    if ((firstLogin == 0) && (firstMobile == 0) && (firstOtp == 0) && (firstInfo == 0)) {
      setState(() {
        print("first launch");
        Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(LoginScreen.routeName);
      });
    } else {
      setState(() {
        print("not first launch");
        Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(LandingSection.routeName);
      });
    }

  }
```

> And calling the `setValue()` in `initState()`

I am looking forward for solution.